# Run all blocks when-then, even if one fail

Tags: unit-testing, spock

I have method in specification with multiple blocks when-then

```
def "some test" () {
    given:
    ...

    when: 
    ...
    then: // <-- faild
    ...

    when:
    ...
    then:
    ...
}
```

If first one block when-then faild, then second one doesn't execute. Is it possible to execute both even if first one faild?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible and makes no sense, because when you have multiple `when` in one test case then there is some relation between them and success of the second `when` is then conditioned by the success of the first `when` and the behavior to fail the whole test case is wanted.

If you do not assume that relation then separate it into two or more individual test cases:

```
void 'some test'() {
    given:
    ...
    when: 
    ...
    then:
    ...
}

void 'another test'()
    given:
    ...
    when: 'second when from some test'
    ...
    then: 'second then from some test'
    ...
}
```

If you have multiple `when`+`then` to share the `given` section then you can have global setup:

```
class MySpec extends Specification {    
    setup() {
        // code from the given section
    }

    void 'some test'() {
        ...
    }

    void 'another test'() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Or you can create shared method which will be called in all test cases when it's needed.

And if your multiple `when` blocks differs only in used values then consider using a `where` block. See the documentation: http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/data_driven_testing.html#data-tables

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I changed when-then to expect-where and now it's ok. 
I tested method with list as argument, so I thought that when-then block is a good solution.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, using of `where` is then the best approach. From my point of view Spock's `where` is the biggest advantage over JUnit ;-)

Comment: Yes, currently I write integration tests in Junit5 and unit tests in spock so I see the difference between `where` and `@ParameterizedTest` ;)